# Asynchronous API calls from PHP application using Slim + Guzzle

Tags: php, api, asynchronous, slim, guzzle

I'm working on a php application using **Slim** framework. My application homepage is making about 20 REST API calls, which is slowing down the page load.

I read that I can use Http Clients like **Guzzle** to call these API's asynchronously but I couldn't find any article that tells how to use Guzzle with Slim.

Can someone tell how to use Guzzle with Slim.

Or is there any other solution that can speed up the page load?

N.B: I'm a novice in PHP

Comment: Please show us some example code of your "page loading" functionality.

Comment: CMIIW, slim application run on web server request, will be run in single thread. So asynchronous call is not relevant here. You can have php use  multiple thread with pthread extension on cli. My suggestion is to cache api response, for example, with redis, or file or database.

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara is correct. Async requests aren't going to do much here - caching would be a much better approach. Or reduce the number of requests needed to render the page - needing 20 seems excessive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use Guzzle with Slim, you need to

Install it by running composer

```
$ composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:~6.0
```

[Guzzle installation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/overview.html#installation)
[Guzzle Quickstart](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html)

Create dependency registration, for example

```
<?php

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$container = $app->getContainer();

$container['httpClient'] = function ($cntr) {
    return new Client();             
};
```

and put it somewhere where it will be executed when `index.php` the main bootstrap file is loaded.

Then in your code, you can get guzzle instance from container

```
$guzzle = $container->httpClient;
```

For example if you have following route

```
$app->get('/example', App\Controllers\Example::class);
```

And controller `Example` as follow

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

class Example
{
    private $httpClient;

    public function __construct(ClientInterface $httpClient) 
    {
        $this->httpClient = $httpClient;
    }

    public function __invoke(Request $request, Response $response, array $args)
    {
        //call api, etc..etc
       $apiResponse = $this->httpClient->get('http://api.blabla.org/get');
       //do something with api response
       return $response;
    }
}
```

To inject guzzle instance to `Example` controller, you create its dependency registration

```
use App\Controllers\Example;

$container[Example::class] = function ($cntr) {
    return new Example($cntr->httpClient);
}
```

To speed up your page load, if you are API developer then start from there. If you are not API developer and have no control, try to think if you can reduce number of API calls by removing non essential ones. Or as last resort, cache API call response to storage that is faster for your application to retrieve later.

For example using redis.
You calculate hash of API url call including its querystring and use hash as key to access cached API call response.